# How map() works with dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

If I have a dictionary as:

`dmap = {0:'Mon',1:'Tue',2:'Wed',3:'Thu',4:'Fri',5:'Sat',6:'Sun'}`

Now if i have values 0-7 in my `'Day of Week'` column in dataframe `df`, i want to replace the values with corresponding day names e.g `'Day of Week'` column should contain now 'Mon', 'Tue'.... instead of values. And i am doing this by:

`df['Day of Week'] = df['Day of Week'].map(dmap)`

It works fine, but i don't understand what is actually going on behind the scenes. Isnt' map() taking two arguments `function` and `sequence`, then how is this working?

Comment: The sequence it is running on is `df['Day of Week']`

Comment: Are you mixing up these two maps? https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with `map` the function … try reading documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html#

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the `map` builtin. This is [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), which accepts a "function, `collections.abc.Mapping` subclass or `Series`" as its first argument.

Answer (score 1):

To follow on @Amadan answer, you can also use another pandas function ([pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)) if you just need to replace your values within a dataframe.

```
df.replace({'Day of Week': dmap}, inplace=True)
```